# sidr jquery plugin side menu wont appear

Tags: jquery

Am i missing out anything? Did i call properly? plugin is from http://www.berriart.com/sidr/ 
Also it generated a plain page for me. I am sure the CSS path is correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <head>  
        <!-- Your stuff -->

        <!-- Include Sidr bundled CSS theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/jquery.sidr.dark.css">



      </head>
      <body>



       <a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr">Toggle menu</a>

    <div id="sidr">
      <!-- Your content -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>     <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#simple-menu').sidr();
      });

    </script>   

              <a href="http://www.boysgeneration.net/sidebar/#simple-menu"> Activate here</a>



        <!-- Include jQuery -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include the Sidr JS -->
        <script src="jquery.sidr.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is jQuery working on your page? You can do a simple check with `if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {alert('No jQuery boo!')}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call jqueries file before your code

```
<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include the Sidr JS -->
<script src="jquery.sidr.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#simple-menu').sidr();
});
```

and try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#simple-menu').sidr({name:'sidr'});
});
```